# Expression could not be translated error when using a local list to with Any clause in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a list of DateTime objects (local list) and I want to use it in a query with EF core as follows:

```
var teacher = _appDataContext
    .Teachers
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(booking.Teacher.Id))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        IsConflicted = x
            .Bookings
            .Any(y => booking.StartingTimes.Any(z => y.StartingTime <= z && z < y.EndingTime)) // booking.StartingTimes is a local list.
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But whenever I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Booking>
    .Where(b0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Teacher
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer.Outer)
        IsNullable: False
    ), "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Teacher
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer.Outer)
        IsNullable: False
    ), "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(b0, "TeacherId"))
    .Any(b0 => __booking_StartingTimes_4
        .Any(z => b0.StartingTime <= z && z < b0.EndingTime))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Does this mean that I cannot do this kind of comparison in a local list? Are there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: EF is trying to build an SQL query so if StartingTimes isn't a mapped relationship it cannot give criteria to the database. Your options are to either build the query to use any mapped relationships you used to derive the StartingTimes through, or you're materializing the entire list of Teachers/Bookings to do that check in memory.

Comment: @StevePy The list of StartingTimes does not come from a query, it is created locally, and therefore I wont be able to go on with the first option. As for the second option, while it can be done, it is impractical since the list of teachers' bookings can have many records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I was able to solve the issue. My solution however requires `LinqKit` package to be added:

First I built a predicate incrementally by looping over the local `StartingTimes` as follows:

```
Expression<Func<Booking, bool>> predicate = x => false;
booking.StartingTimes.ToList().ForEach(x => { predicate = predicate.Or(y => y.StartingTime <= x && x < y.EndingTime); });
```

Afterward, I just used the predicate as a paramater to the `Any` method as follows:

```
var teacher = _appDataContext
    .Teachers
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(booking.Teacher.Id))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        IsConflicted = x
            .Bookings
            .Any(predicate.Invoke())
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```